# Why index on nested jsonb in postgres is casting to text?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to add index on nested field in a jsonb column in postgres using the following line of code:

```
create index "links_cast(blocks -> 'settings' -> 'theme' ->> 'id')_index" on links (cast(blocks->'settings'->'theme'->>'id' AS text));
```

I have tried this also:

```
create index "links_cast(blocks -> 'settings' -> 'theme' ->> 'id')_index" on links ((blocks -> 'settings' -> 'theme' ->> 'id'));
```

but the result is same. when in the PhpStorm, I checked the `Modify Table`->`Indexes` tab, I faced with the following:
[image]
I am wondering why it is converted my index from -> to ->> and converted whole of the parent and grandparent objects (settings and theme) to text?
if I change some other key except `theme`, for example change a `color` key inside the `settings` and update it time to time, will it rewrite whole of the theme->id index again?
if yes, how I can avoid it?

Comment: "I am wondering why it is converted my index from -> to ->>"  Both of your CREATE statements have exactly one `->>`, and your introspection also shows exactly one `->>`.  What do you think is getting converted here?

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Comment: @jjanes , it converted my parent object (for example 'settings') to text by adding ->> to it. but I only want to have index on 'id'

Comment: Your image clearly shows that it did not.  Still shows -> after settings, **not** ->>.

Comment: the section you mentioned, is the name of index, the right side is important @jjanes